# Can a list of objects be made and operated on in a BASH environment

Tags: linux, bash, list, unix, object

I am working in a `bash` environment and am trying to make a list of sample names; each of which will be fed into a set of commands. Creating lists in R and Python is easy. However, I have not been able to work out if or how an equivalent list variables can be created and accessed in `bash`.

For example, to make a list in python one could write:

```
samples=[sample1 sample2 sample3]
```

To access the first variable in the list, one could use:

```
currentSample = samples[0]
```

Can similar operations be performed in `bash` using a list of text strings?

Comment: what's the problem with bash array? And by the way you are not accessing the first object of the list in your example, you are assigning its value to variable

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "object" -- bash is not object-oriented, so it doesn't have the concept of an object. Pretty much all bash deals with are text strings (e.g. a bash array is just an array of strings).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the example of what you want:

```
samples=(sample1 sample2 sample3)
currentSample=${samples[0]}
echo "$currentSample"
echo "${samples[0]}"
```

Output:

```
sample1 
sample1
```

As you can see you can assign array's value to a variable or use its value directly.